# Installing and putting packages in library

Tags: r, dplyr, package

Does anybody know what this means and how do I fix it?

```
> library(dplyr) Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dplyr’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):  
   there is no package called ‘Rcpp’ 
In addition: Warning message: package ‘dplyr’ was built under R version 3.4.
```

Comment: you have to install `Rcpp`  which is required by `dplyr`

Comment: `install.packages("Rcpp")`?

Comment: you can as well install `Rccp`  and its dependencies to avoid further errors `install.packages("Rccp", dependencies = TRUE)`

Comment: It's still saying the same message when I installed Rcpp

Comment: Perhaps the install of `Rcpp` failed; can you double-check?